# mongodb integration with windows 10 and wamp 64 bit

Tags: php, mongodb, 64-bit, windows-10, wampserver

I installed mongodb on **windows10**. But, couldnt install mongodb briver on my wamp.

**Mongodb version**:2.6.1

[image: Mongodb running at my cmd prompt]

**Wamp version:** 5.5.12

**compiler**: MSVC11(visual C++ 2012)

**Operating System**: Windows 10 64 bit.

**mongodb dll used**:php_mongo-1.6.8-5.5-vcl11-x86_64.dll

[image]

I renamed the dll to php_mongo.dll and in php INI file i added extension=php_mongo.dll.

I restart the wamp and done all the possible things. But, the mongodb is still not showing in phpinfo page and the new mongo() instance is giving fatal error. Please help me. I am probing since two days.

Comment: Don't provide all these informations by embedding them in pictures; use the formatting features of Stackoverflow.

Comment: WAMP most times has multiple php.ini be sure the Php is using the right one. Also, did you restart Apache after your modification?

Comment: I am using the correct PHP.ini selecting from the wamp notification icon. located in D:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\. I restarted the wamp as well. But, nothing works for me.